# crash app signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE)

Tags: java, android

i have an android app that uses a libv2ray.aar to check v2ray config if its available `Libv2ray.measureOutboundDelay(config)`. but when i use this method a few times to check several configs, sometimes the application crashes. i don't have access to .aar file to check the codes. its has `.so` files.
but the logcat is:

```
2023-11-28 15:18:23.159 20739-20739 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  Revision: '4'
2023-11-28 15:18:23.159 20739-20739 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  ABI: 'arm64'
2023-11-28 15:18:23.159 20739-20739 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  Processor: '4'
2023-11-28 15:18:23.159 20739-20739 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  Timestamp: 2023-11-28 15:18:22.724553947+0330
2023-11-28 15:18:23.159 20739-20739 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  Process uptime: 67s
2023-11-28 15:18:23.159 20739-20739 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  Cmdline: and.test.com
2023-11-28 15:18:23.159 20739-20739 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  pid: 20410, tid: 20432, name: RenderThread  >>> and.test.com <<<
2023-11-28 15:18:23.159 20739-20739 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  uid: 10563
2023-11-28 15:18:23.159 20739-20739 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
2023-11-28 15:18:23.159 20739-20739 DEBUG                   crash_dump64                         A  Abort message: 'fdsan: failed to exchange ownership of file descriptor: fd 164 is owned by unique_fd 0x715ac313bc, was expected to be unowned'
crash : and.test.com,10563
2023-11-28 15:18:23.199  1587-20742 ActivityTaskManager     system_server                        W    Force finishing activity and.test.com/.myactivity
```

i put `Libv2ray.measureOutboundDelay(config)` method in try-catch to handle the issue and avoid being crashed but still crashes.

I know that there are bugs in the v2ray lib that cause this issue, but i just want to pervent the app from being crashed, like just ignore if any errors occurs in the lib, but my `try-catch`  like not working on this

Comment: any idea how to prevent crash?